# How do I make a square table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

How can I make a perfectly square table in LaTeX?  Each cell will just have a single character in it. I'm trying to print a pretty [tabula recta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_recta) as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Related Question: [A table with square cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/a-table-with-square-cells)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
\newcount\trrow
\newcount\trcol
\makeatletter
\def\maketrrow{%
        \begingroup
        \loop\ifnum\trcol<26
                \count@\numexpr \trrow + \trcol + `A\relax
                \ifnum\count@>`Z
                        \advance\count@-26
                \fi
                \hbox to\baselineskip{\hss\char\count@\hss}%
                \advance\trcol\@ne
        \repeat
        \endgroup
}

\newcommand\tabularecta[1][\baselineskip]{%
        \vbox{%
                \fontsize{\f@size}{#1}\selectfont
                \hsize\dimexpr 27\baselineskip + .4\p@ \relax
                \parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@
                \trrow\z@
                \leavevmode
                \hbox to\baselineskip{\hfil}%
                \strut\vrule
                \maketrrow
                \par
                \hrule
                \loop\ifnum\trrow<26
                        \leavevmode
                        \trcol\z@
                        \hbox to\baselineskip{\hss\char\numexpr\trrow + `A\relax\hss}%
                        \strut\vrule
                        \maketrrow
                        \par
                        \advance\trrow\@ne
                \repeat
        }%
}
\makeatother
```

Just place a `\tabularecta` wherever you want it to appear. You can use font size changes like `\small` if you want. Since the spacing is based entirely on the baseline, you can simply change it using `\fontsize{..}{..}\selectfont`, or for convenience, you can give `\tabularecta` an optional argument that is the size you want for each cell.

The implementation is straight forward. It iterates over the rows and then over the columns placing boxes of the appropriate size filled with the desired character inside.

Comment: @TH Nice implementation of `looping` through an alphabet. I would use two arguments, one for fontsize and another for baseline, that way you can scale the whole table easily - you never know cryptographers might want to use more than 26 letters!

Comment: Very nice! One question: The `.4\p@` are the width of the `\vrule`, yes?

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah. I'm not even positive that's the right width. I briefly googled, saw that number and plugged it in. Initially, I used `\hbox to\z@{\hss\strut\vrule\hss}` but then I figured that probably was too crowded.

Comment: @Yiannis: Well, you can just change the fontsize before the `\tabularecta`. E.g., `\tiny` before it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt, you can make each cell of the same height and width by

```
\setupTABLE[each][each][width=2em,height=2em,align={middle,middle}]
```

If you want to see how to generate the output as a loop, have a look at a [similar example](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Loops_without_worrying_about_expansion) on the context wiki.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough (okay, any) ConTeXt to turn that into a compilable example. Will the baselines of each character in the row line up? If so, that's a pretty nice solution.

Comment: Yes, the baselines are aligned. Internally, each cell is a framed (one of the core ConTeXt constructs), and the option `align={middle, middle}` is translated to `align=middle` and `location=lohi`. The key `location=lohi` aligns at the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  rows = {3em, rowsep = 2pt},
  columns = {3em, colsep = 2pt},
  cells = {m,c},
  hlines,
  vlines,
}
  A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\ 
  B & C & D & E & F & G & A \\ 
  C & D & E & F & G & A & B \\ 
  D & E & F & G & A & B & C \\ 
  E & F & G & A & B & C & D \\
  F & G & A & B & C & D & E \\ 
  G & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]