# Automatically generated BINGO cards

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

I am trying to automatically generate a series of BINGO cards.  So, I need a 5 x 5 table with square cells that allow text wrapping.  I also want to randomly assign a word to each cell from a "bank" of 30 different words, and I need the center cell to, of course, be labeled "FREE".  This means that for each card, 6 words from the bank will not be used.  I know that this can be accomplished with tikz and some macros, but I am not familiar with the macros needed to randomly select the words, and I am having trouble finding adequate help on the web.  Can someone please help?

Thanks!

--
I mostly figured out my own question; however, I still have one major problem as stated after the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\random}[5]{%
\pgfmathparse{random(5)}%
\ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
\or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\randomtwo}[6]{
    \pgfmathparse{random(6)}
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
    \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\randomthree}[6]{
    \pgfmathparse{random(6)}
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
    \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\randomfour}[6]{
    \pgfmathparse{random(6)}
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
    \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\randomfive}[6]{
    \pgfmathparse{random(6)}
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
    \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6
\fi%
}

\newcommand*{\randomsix}[6]{
    \pgfmathparse{random(6)}
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
    \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6
\fi%
}

\def\NumOfColumns{5}%
\def\Sequence{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}%

\newcommand{\Size}{3.25cm}
\tikzset{Square/.style={
inner sep=0pt,
text width=\Size, 
minimum size=\Size,
draw=black,
align=center,
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, thick, x=\Size,y=\Size]
\foreach \row in \Sequence{%
    \foreach \col in \Sequence {%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\col+\NumOfColumns*(\row-1)}
        \def\NodeText{\random{\randomtwo{radioactivity}{$\alpha$ particle}{$\gamma$-ray}{in--situ leaching}{half--life, $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$}{GM counter}}{\randomthree{Manhattan Project}{$3-5$ \%}{$^{232}$Th}{breeder}{greenhouse gas}{ICP--MS}}{\randomfour{NRC}{conversion}{solid}{Rocky Flats}{smoke detector}{Trinity}}{\randomfive{START}{Yucca Mountain}{Chart of the Nuclides}{Chernobyl}{Savannah River Site}{Hanford Site}}{\randomsix{PUREX}{UO$_2$}{Y--12}{Bq}{LSC}{gaseous diffusion}}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ColRowProduce}{\col*\row}
        \IfEq{\ColRowProduce}{9}{% If is center square
            \node [] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {FREE};
        }{
            \node [Square] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {\large \NodeText};
        }
    }
}    
\end{tikzpicture}                       
\end{document}
```

The biggest problem is that I get repeat words on my BINGO card.  Can I set up a loop to prevent this?  Also, if anyone has a way of cleaning up this code, I would be grateful.

Comment: Related Question: [A table with square cells](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/a-table-with-square-cells).  You should use this to get started and get as far as you can; Then post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that those trying to help have something to start from.

Comment: It looks like you only need `\random` and `\randomtwo`, randoms 3-6 are the same as `\randomtwo`.  Is there a reason that you've grouped your entries as sets of 6?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the original question, I need a bank of thirty words to choose from, and `\newcommand` only takes 9 arguments.  I could accomplish the same with fewer `\random` commands, but it means that there will not be an equal probability of each of the words being selected.  In all reality, I need a command that allows random selection between thirty different words, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's something that works.  I'm not sure about its efficiency however.  The code below selects random items from a user entered list of items and from these builds a randomized sequence of 24 items (25 less the center square) without duplicates.  When `\NodeText` is called, an item is removed from the randomized list and placed in the node.  An error is issued when too few items are provided (i.e. less than 24) and there isn't an upper limit on the number of items that can be supplied.  For each new bingo card that you want to generate, you just call `\setItems` and regenerate a card. Comments/suggested improvements on the code are welcomed!

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\input{random.tex}
\newcount\randomnum
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_my_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l_my_tmp_items_seq
\seq_new:N \g_my_randomized_seq
\int_new:N \l_tmp_int
\msg_new:nnnn {bingo} {Too~few~items!} {Provide~at~least~24~items!}{}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_item:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_remove_all:Nn {Nx}

\NewDocumentCommand {\myItems} {m}
    {
      \seq_clear:N \g_my_items_seq % clear item list 
      \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_my_items_seq {;} {#1} % put item list in seq
      \int_compare:nNnT {\seq_count:N \g_my_items_seq} < {24} {\msg_error:nn {bingo} {Too~few~items!}} % check whether there are enough items
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setItems}{}
{
\seq_set_eq:NN \l_my_tmp_items_seq \g_my_items_seq % put in temp seq so that multiple cards can be produced
\prg_replicate:nn {24} %generate random list of 24 items
    {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmp_int {\seq_count:N \l_my_tmp_items_seq}% set current length of list
        \setrannum{\randomnum}{1}{\int_use:N \l_tmp_int} % choose random num up to length of seq
        \seq_put_right:Nx \g_my_randomized_seq {\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_items_seq {\the\randomnum}}% grab corresponding item and put in tmp seq
        \seq_remove_all:Nx \l_my_tmp_items_seq {\seq_item:Nn \l_my_tmp_items_seq {\the\randomnum}}%delete that item from temp seq
    }
\seq_clear:N \l_my_tmp_items_seq %clear temp seq when done
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\NodeText}{}
    {
        \seq_gpop_right:NN \g_my_randomized_seq \l_tmpa_tl %pop item from randomized seq into token list
        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl %use that item.
    }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\NumOfColumns{5}%
\def\Sequence{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}%

\newcommand{\Size}{3.25cm}
\tikzset{Square/.style={
inner sep=0pt,
text width=\Size, 
minimum size=\Size,
draw=black,
align=center,
}
}

\begin{document}
%\myItems{this;will;produce;an;error;because;there;aren't;enough;items}

\myItems{radioactivity;$\alpha$ particle;$\gamma$-ray;in--situ leaching;half--life, $t_{\frac{1}{2}}$;GM counter;Manhattan Project;$3-5$ \%;$^{232}$Th;breeder;greenhouse gas;ICP--MS;conversion;solid;Rocky Flats;smoke detector;Trinity;START;Yucca Mountain;Chart of Nuclides;Chernobyl;Savannah River Site;Hanford Site;PUREX;UO$_2$;Y--12;Bq;LSC;gaseous diffusion}

\setItems

\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, thick, x=\Size,y=\Size]
\foreach \row in \Sequence{%
    \foreach \col in \Sequence {%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\col+\NumOfColumns*(\row-1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ColRowProduce}{\col*\row}
        \IfEq{\ColRowProduce}{9}{% If is center square
            \node [] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {FREE};
        }{
            \node [Square] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {\large \NodeText};
        }
    }
}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\setItems

\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=black, thick, x=\Size,y=\Size]
\foreach \row in \Sequence{%
    \foreach \col in \Sequence {%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\col+\NumOfColumns*(\row-1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ColRowProduce}{\col*\row}
        \IfEq{\ColRowProduce}{9}{% If is center square
            \node [] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {FREE};
        }{
            \node [Square] at ($(\col,-\row)-(0.5,0.5)$) {\large \NodeText};
        }
    }
}    
\end{tikzpicture}                 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Scott --  Thanks so much for your help ... this solution is really really close.  I'm not familiar with the code you used in the preamble, so I don't really know where to begin to correct the issues with `\setrannum`.  However, I will work on it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Shanna, it works now :)

Comment: This is awesome!  -- It works perfectly, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: So I've been looking for something like this for ages! ...the only problem is I can't quite get it to work. I'm under the impression that I'm supposed to replace the "N" with \setrannum with the number of items I want from the sequence, (so I've been changing it to 24), but is there more I'm supposed to adjust before this will finally compile for me? The closest I've gotten is 101 errors.

Comment: Hmmm. I've been able to get some success by using an online compiler (writeLaTeX) instead of my normal compiler (TeXnicCenter), but now when it compiles a few of the bingo squares are blank.

Comment: @aklingensmith Hi there, one of the functions used in the code was deprecated, I replaced it with the new version.  I'm also getting a blank that I can't explain at the moment.  I'll have a look and see if I can figure out why.

Comment: @aklingensmith  I think it's fixed now.  Either I was out to lunch, or sequences used to be indexed starting at 0, and are now indexed starting at 1.  I changed the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>Here's my version using `arrayjobx`. First you specify a list of thirty words. In each iteration, a word from a list of decreasing length is chosen, then the chosen word is replaced by  last word of the list.</strike>

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{trimspaces}

\makeatletter
\def\trimspace#1{\trim@spaces@in{#1}}
\makeatother

\newarray\randomwords
\readarray{randomwords}{%
Mouse   & Philanthropy & Ember     & Vermillion & Saber       &
Tumor   & Cook         & Lick      & Money      & Superfluous &
Quiz    & Thesis       & Dent      & Head       & Drum        &
Light   & Key          & Purple    & Million    & Retro       &
Loud    & Gear         & Hijack    & Trophy     & Long        &
Shotgun & Asphalt      & Scripture & Pollution  & Crack}

\newcommand{\bingofield}{}
\newcommand{\replacementword}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fieldnumber}{25-5*\y+\x}
        \ifthenelse{\fieldnumber=13}{\xdef\bingofield{BINGO}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\fieldnumber<13 \OR \fieldnumber>13}%
            {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxvalue}{30+1-\fieldnumber}
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myrandom}{random(\maxvalue)}
                \checkrandomwords(\myrandom)\trimspace\cachedata
                \xdef\bingofield{\cachedata}
                \checkrandomwords(\maxvalue)\trimspace\cachedata
                \xdef\replacementword{\cachedata}
                \randomwords(\myrandom)={\replacementword}
            }{}
        \node[above right,text width=1.7cm,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,align=center] at (\x*2,\y*2) {\tiny \bingofield};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**@MichaelA:** I'll do you one better. As the previous version clearly doesn't work (having all different words would be a total chance encounter, but not guaranteed) I totally rewrote it. Just change the `cellsize` to your liking. You can also create bigger grids (e.g. 7x7) by adjusting the `gridsize`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\randomwords}{%
;Mouse;Philanthropy;Ember;Vermillion;Saber;Tumor;Cook%
;Lick;Money;Superfluous;Quiz;Thesis;Dent;Head;Drum;Light%
;Key;Purple;Million;Retro;Loud;Gear;Hijack;Trophy;Long%
;Shotgun;Asphalt;Scripture;Pollution;Crack;}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cellsize}{3.3}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridsize}{5}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fieldcount}{\gridsize*\gridsize-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\bingo}{\fieldcount/2}
\StrCount{\randomwords}{;}[\numwords]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \f in {0,...,\fieldcount}
    { \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{mod(\f,\gridsize)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{div(\f,\gridsize)}
        \draw ({\x*\cellsize},{\y*\cellsize}) rectangle ({(\x+1)*\cellsize},{(\y+1)*\cellsize});
        \ifthenelse{\f=\bingo}
        {   \node at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {BINGO!};
        }
        {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxvalue}{\numwords-1-\f)}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myrandom}{random(\maxvalue)}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynextrandom}{\myrandom+1}
          \StrBetween[\myrandom,\mynextrandom]{\randomwords}{;}{;}[\randomword]
          \StrDel{\randomwords}{\randomword;}[\randomwords]
          \xdef\randomwords{\randomwords}
            %\node at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {\myrandom-\maxvalue-\randomword};
            \node at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {\randomword};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

Just for the fun of it added some row and column headers, now you can use it as a manual random word generator or as a "copy protection" for your oldschool adventure game. I also adde some color.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\randomwords}{%
;lavish;cheap;swift;fence;hospital;society;condemned;summer;teeny-tiny;scary;door;broad;wheel;second%
;merciful;return;prevent;enormous;loud;neighborly;crown;proud;open;fearless;trap;grape;run;overflow%
;clumsy;land;bare;beef;icky;turkey;strange;lace;listen;spade;size;sweltering;basket;rabbits;search%
;sleepy;guarantee;large;pot;mass;paint;admit;calendar;kind;hammer;bruise;ticket;cuddly;ocean%
;psychotic;connection;carpenter;sack;spurious;coil;imagine;laugh;riddle;muddled;juice;army;berserk%
;true;slimy;incandescent;hose;nippy;unhealthy;side;rice;lick;public;need;snatch;pear;aspiring;back%
;oil;filthy;stale;authority;round;succeed;cattle;snake;expert;sail;aback;whisper;powerful;charming%
;handsome;rifle;profit;longing;division;needless;saw;nonchalant;nauseating;cloth;fax;suggest;copy%
;chop;capable;cough;gullible;simple;test;children;race;business;}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cellsize}{2}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\gridsize}{11}


\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fieldcount}{\gridsize*\gridsize-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\bingo}{\fieldcount/2}
\StrCount{\randomwords}{;}[\numwords]
\newcounter{myletter}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\minusgrid}{\gridsize-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \f in {0,...,\fieldcount}
    { \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{mod(\f,\gridsize)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{div(\f,\gridsize)}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycolor}{mod(\f,2)*100}
        \draw[fill=yellow!\mycolor!red!10] ({\x*\cellsize},{\y*\cellsize}) rectangle ({(\x+1)*\cellsize},{(\y+1)*\cellsize});
        \ifthenelse{\f=\bingo}
        {   \node[rotate=45] at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {BINGO!};
        }
        {   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxvalue}{\numwords-1-\f)}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myrandom}{random(\maxvalue)}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynextrandom}{\myrandom+1}
          \StrBetween[\myrandom,\mynextrandom]{\randomwords}{;}{;}[\randomword]
          \StrDel{\randomwords}{\randomword;}[\randomwords]
          \xdef\randomwords{\randomwords}
            %\node at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {\myrandom-\maxvalue-\randomword};
            \node[rotate=45] at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {\randomword};
        }
        \ifthenelse{\x=0}
        {   \draw[fill=blue!10] ({\x*\cellsize},{\y*\cellsize}) rectangle ({(\x-0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+1)*\cellsize});
            \node at ({(\x-0.25)*\cellsize},{(\y+0.5)*\cellsize}) {\pgfmathparse{int(\gridsize-\y)}\pgfmathresult};
        }{}
        \ifthenelse{\y=\minusgrid}
        {   \draw[fill=blue!10] ({\x*\cellsize},{(\y+1)*\cellsize}) rectangle ({(\x+1)*\cellsize},{(\y+1.5)*\cellsize});
            \pgfmathparse{int(\x+1)}
            \setcounter{myletter}{\pgfmathresult}
            \node at ({(\x+0.5)*\cellsize},{(\y+1.25)*\cellsize}) {\Alph{myletter}};
        }{}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, I don't know enough about the packages you have used to tell where they're coming from, but there are a couple of duplicates in your table: Dent and Scripture.

Comment: How would you increase the display size of the grid? If I just change the text size, for example `{\tiny \bingofield}` to `{\small \bingofield}` or change the minimum width and height of each cell, it simply distorts the grid and misaligns all the text.

Comment: @MichaelA: If you already rewrote the broken random choice part, you could also simply declare a variable outside the picture like `\newcommand{\grid}{2.5}` and change the node line to `\node[above right, minimum width=\grid*1cm,minimum height=\grid*1cm,draw] at (\x*\grid,\y*\grid) {\tiny \bingofield};`