# How to randomly generate more than 10 BINGO cards in latex?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, overleaf, seq

I've used code similar to the one provided in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63440/279612, and I'm only getting 10 Bingo Cards. I would like to generate more than 10. I would like to create 80 Bingo Cards, one each for my student. I know that if we refresh the given code and compile it again, it would generate 10 other Bingo Cards. But was just wondering if we could generate as many as we want all at once. Thanks in advance for your reply. I've recently signed up, so sorry if I haven't provided the question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

I had no motivation to read the other code, so I wrote some bingo card creating code.

The approach here uses two macros:

- `\randbingothingies` takes a single comma separated list as an argument of all the things which could appear on your cards.
- `\randbingocards` takes an optional followed by three mandatory arguments. The optional argument can contain a key=value list with the keys `width`, `height` and `hpad` (horizontal padding), specifying the size of each field. The mandatory arguments are numbers of rows, columns, and cards.

The following creates 80 cards each with 4 rows and 5 columns. Each thingy from the thingies-list only appears once in each card.

A word of warning: If your biggest contents get higher than the specified height they will silently overprint vertically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__lpadmini_randbingo_thingies_seq
\seq_new:N \g__lpadmini_randbingo_tmp_seq
\seq_new:N \l__lpadmini_randbingo_line_seq
\int_new:N \l__lpadmini_randbingo_columns_int
\keys_define:nn { lpadmini/randbingo }
  {
     width  .dim_set:N = \l__lpadmini_randbingo_wd_dim
    ,height .dim_set:N = \l__lpadmini_randbingo_ht_dim
    ,hpad   .code:n    = \setlength \tabcolsep { \dim_eval:n {#1} }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { lpadmini/randbingo } { insufficient-thingies }
  { Not~ enough~ thingies~ provided. }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__lpadmini_randbingo_line:
  {
    \rule
      [ -.5\l__lpadmini_randbingo_ht_dim ]
      { \c_zero_dim }
      { \l__lpadmini_randbingo_ht_dim }
    \seq_clear:N \l__lpadmini_randbingo_line_seq
    \prg_replicate:nn \l__lpadmini_randbingo_columns_int
      {
        \seq_gpop:NN \g__lpadmini_randbingo_tmp_seq \l_tmpa_tl
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l__lpadmini_randbingo_line_seq
          { \exp_not:N \__lpadmini_randbingo_cell:n { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } }
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__lpadmini_randbingo_line_seq { & } \\
    \hline
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lpadmini_randbingo_cell:n #1
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
    \smash
      {
        \raisebox { \dim_eval:n { .5\depth - .5\height } }
          {
            \dim_compare:nNnTF
                { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
                >
                \l__lpadmini_randbingo_wd_dim
              { \parbox { \l__lpadmini_randbingo_wd_dim } { \centering #1 } }
              { \makebox [ \l__lpadmini_randbingo_wd_dim ] [ c ] { #1 } }
          }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \randbingothingies { m }
  { \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__lpadmini_randbingo_thingies_seq {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \randbingocards { O{} m m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { lpadmini/randbingo } {#1}
      \int_compare:nNnT
          { #2 * #3 }
          >
          { \seq_count:N \l__lpadmini_randbingo_thingies_seq }
        { \msg_error:nn { lpadmini/randbingo } { insufficient-thingies } }
      \int_set:Nn \l__lpadmini_randbingo_columns_int {#3}
      \int_step_inline:nn {#4}
        {
          \seq_set_eq:NN
            \g__lpadmini_randbingo_tmp_seq \l__lpadmini_randbingo_thingies_seq
          \seq_shuffle:N \g__lpadmini_randbingo_tmp_seq
          \noindent
          \begin{tabular}{|*{#3}{c|}}
            \hline
            \prg_replicate:nn {#2} \__lpadmini_randbingo_line:
          \end{tabular}
          \par
          \vfill
        }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\randbingothingies{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,Some
extrordinary long field}
\randbingocards[width=1.6cm,height=2cm,hpad=2mm]{4}{5}{80}
\end{document}
```

First page of output:

[image]