# LaTeX, formatting entries in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I've seen plenty of problems with making tables in LaTeX formatted the way the programmer would prefer. And some of those have helped me fix my own doument to the point I am not at  I am creating a "bingo" document. It's 4x4 table. Each entry contains a number in the center. Each "slot" is a square. I have two issues. When I run the code (see below), the numbers in the right-most column aren't centered. They are at the top of the "slot" centered horizontally relative to the "slot". I've tried many different things to get these entries where they need to be.... but I'm not sure what to do now. The other thing I would like is to change the font size of the numbers to make them larger.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} |  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm} |}
\hline\hline
\Huge {\bf 12} & \Huge {\bf 0} & \Huge {\bf 9} & \Huge {\bf 19} \\[3.5cm]
\hline
\Huge {\bf 15} & \Huge {\bf 4} & \Huge {\bf 2} & \Huge {\bf 3} \\[3.5cm]
\hline
\Huge {\bf 5} & \Huge {\bf 17} & \Huge {\bf 7} & \Huge {\bf 11} \\[3.5cm]
\hline
\Huge {\bf 16} & \Huge {\bf 18} & \Huge {\bf 8} & \Huge {\bf 14} \\[3.5cm]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I would like to stay as simple as I can with the code. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: There's a separate Stack Exchange site specifically for TeX questions: [tex.se].

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would me nice.

Comment: This is probably of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/a-table-with-square-cells