# Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

Friends, I'm trying to generate a table in which I have all columns equally spaced (same width). In my case, the width for all columns would be the width of the widest column of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b \\
c & Mary had a little lamb
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Any hints? `:)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I've been solving this problem before and I ended with quite a universal solution, see the example (you need to run the code twice to get the correct result):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newlength\eqcol@newlen
\newlength\eqcol@oldlen
\let\eqcol@bc\hfil
\let\eqcol@ec\hfil
\let\eqcol@br\hfil
\let\eqcol@el\hfil
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{%
  >{\setbox0\hbox\bgroup}#1%
  <{\egroup
    \ifdim\wd0<\eqcol@newlen\else\global\eqcol@newlen\wd0\fi
    \ifdim\wd0<\eqcol@oldlen\else\global\eqcol@oldlen\wd0\fi
    \hbox to \eqcol@oldlen{%
      \csname eqcol@b#1\endcsname
      \box0 %
      \csname eqcol@e#1\endcsname
    }%
  }%
}
\newcount\eqcol@count
\def\eqcolRead{%
  \global\advance\eqcol@count1 %
  \eqcol@oldlen5em\relax
  \csname eqcol@def@\romannumeral\eqcol@count\endcsname
}
\def\eqcolWrite{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname eqcol@def@\romannumeral\eqcol@count\endcsname
    {\global\eqcol@oldlen\the\eqcol@newlen\relax}%
  }%
  \global\eqcol@newlen0pt\relax
}
\let\eqcol@old@tabular\tabular
\def\tabular{\eqcolRead\eqcol@old@tabular}
\let\eqcol@old@endtabular\endtabular
\def\endtabular{\eqcol@old@endtabular\eqcolWrite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|el|er|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|ec|er|}
\hline
1 & 22 \\\hline
3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|el|er|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 444444 \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\[
A =
  \eqcolRead\begin{array}{*3{ec}}
  1 & 10000 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}\eqcolWrite
\]

\end{document}
```

The `tabular` environment is tweaked by default, in other cases, you have to do it manually (see the `array` example above).

Answer (score 14):

This is inspired by tohecz, but uses a dedicated environment, which I believe is better.

In a `equalizedtabular` one can use any column specifier, not just `L`, `C` or `R`, but of course only these will be equalized. Two passes are necessary, since the `.aux` file is used, and upon inclusion of an `equalizedtabular` between two of them the first compilation will give wrong results; however, the next run of LaTeX will fix the lengths.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,collcell}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\docellC}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\docellL}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\docellR}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@nameedef}[1]{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\docell}[2]{%
  \sbox\equalizedtablebox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd\equalizedtablebox>\@nameuse{finallen\theequalizedtable}\relax
    \global\@nameedef{finallen\theequalizedtable}{\the\wd\equalizedtablebox}%
  \fi
  \makebox[\@nameuse{startinglen\theequalizedtable}][#1]{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\docellC}[1]{\docell{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\docellL}[1]{\docell{l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\docellR}[1]{\docell{r}{#1}}
\newcounter{equalizedtable}
\newsavebox\equalizedtablebox
\newenvironment{equalizedtabular}[2][c]
  {%
   \stepcounter{equalizedtable}%
   \global\@namedef{finallen\theequalizedtable}{0pt}%
   \@ifundefined{startinglen\theequalizedtable}
    {\@namedef{startinglen\theequalizedtable}{5em}}{}
   \tabular[#1]{#2}%
  }
  {%
   \endtabular
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \write\@auxout{%
       \global\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\@namedef{startinglen\theequalizedtable}%
     {\@nameuse{finallen\theequalizedtable}}%
   }}\x
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{equalizedtabular}{|L|C|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{equalizedtabular}

\begin{equalizedtabular}{|R|C|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4 \\\hline
\end{equalizedtabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I'd change the input syntax a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\paulo#1{\count@#1\relax\leavevmode\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup}
\def\endpaulo{\egroup\dimen@\wd\z@\global\setbox\@ne\null
\setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\z@\loop\unskip\unskip\setbox\z@\lastbox
\ifvoid\z@\else
\global\setbox\@ne\hbox{\hbox to\dimen@{\box\z@\hfil}\penalty\z@\unhbox\@ne}%
\repeat}%
\vbox{\hsize\count@\dimen@\noindent\unhbox\@ne}}

\def\cell#1{\hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\ignorespaces#1\unskip\kern\tabcolsep}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{paulo}{2}
\cell{a}
\cell{b}
\cell{c}
\cell{Mary had a little lamb}
\end{paulo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you know the entry of the widest column, the solution may be as the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\thicklamb}
\settowidth{\thicklamb}{Mary had a little lamb}
\begin{tabular}{p{\thicklamb}p{\thicklamb}}
a & b \\
c & Mary had a little lamb
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This answer picks up a bit from egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139780/4686) and a lot from the [eqparbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{eqtabular}
\newsavebox\eqtabularbox

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\eqtabularbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}%
                   \eqmakebox [\the\c@eqtabular @eqtabular]%
                              {\unhcopy\eqtabularbox}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\eqtabularbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}%
                   \eqmakebox [\the\c@eqtabular @eqtabular][l]%
                              {\unhcopy\eqtabularbox}}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\eqtabularbox}}c<{\end{lrbox}%
                 \eqmakebox [\the\c@eqtabular @eqtabular][r]%
                            {\unhcopy\eqtabularbox}}}


\newenvironment{eqtabular}[2][c]
  {%
   \stepcounter{eqtabular}%
   \tabular[#1]{#2}%
  }
  {%
   \endtabular
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{eqtabular}{|L|L|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\begin{eqtabular}{|R|R|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\begin{eqtabular}{|C|C|}
\hline
11111111111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\begin{eqtabular}{|R|L|}
\hline
11111111111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4444444 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\begin{eqtabular}{|R|C|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\begin{eqtabular}{|L|R|}
\hline
111 & 22 \\\hline
33 & 4 \\\hline
\end{eqtabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: eqparbox]

Comment: at least two latex runs are necessary.

Comment: I would prefer `\unhbox` over `\unhcopy` since you won't need the box again ;)

Comment: @tohecz yes, you are right, I copied-pasted from some other code I had in my files. I will fix it. Actually the box is erased from memory as the tabular character or the newline closes a group, (if I am correct), so the change is a bit cosmetic (I think).

Comment: @tohecz see where my infinite trust in you has led me ? ;-) actually, no it doesn't work with `\unhbox`. It's too early for me in the morning to try to understand that, I hastily re-edited to revert my changes...

Comment: @tohecz I now recall that it is not from my files but from an example in the `eqparbox` documentation that I got the `\unhcopy`. Quick look at the code makes me think there is `\eqp@settowidth` which does a `\settowidth` on the material and then `\eqp@produce@box` which uses a second time the material to actually print the box. So `\unhbox` is not usable within an `eqparbox` box construct.

Comment: I suppose that in that case it is not too early to empty it. The reason is that probably `\eqmakebox` reads the contents twice, and in the first reading the box gets (of course) emptied.

Answer (score 7):

needs at least two runs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newsavebox\CBox \sbox\CBox{ }
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\CWidth{\def\CWidth{1em}}% for the first latex run
\newcolumntype{P}{
  >{\sbox\CBox\bgroup}%         start to save the contents
   p{\CWidth}%                  set the column to the maximal width                  
  <{\egroup%                    end of the savebox
    \ifdim\the\wd\CBox>\CWidth% is the width bigger than the current one 
      \immediate\write\@mainaux{\gdef\string\CWidth{\the\wd\CBox}}\fi%
    \usebox\CBox}}%             write contents into the cell
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|P|P|}\hline
a & b \\\hline
c & Mary had a little lamb\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\sbox\CBox\bgroup...\egroup` expands to `\setbox\CBox=\hbox{\color@setgroup\bgroup\color@endgroup#2}\egroup` which is not what's wanted.

Comment: how do you know what I want??

Comment: Everybody can see you're losing the protection for colors. You're free to use bad macros, if so pleases you, but at least warn users about the risks.

Comment: A hack would be to say `\sbox\CBox\bgroup\aftergroup`, so that `\color@endgroup` will be executed after the brace, keeping the color stack in sync.

Answer (score 7):

This is as good a place as any to pre-introduce the new package I'm working on: `tabstackengine`, which is a front end to my `stackengine` package to provide support for tabbed arguments.  The reason I introduce the package here is because it supports fixed-width tabbing (based on the widest argument) WITH A SINGLE COMPILER PASS, which is the topic of this question.  To do that, one sets the mode `\fixTABwidth{T}` or `\fixTABwidth{F}` before the macro invocation.

With a few exceptions where it doesn't make sense, you can take a `stackengine` macro and add the word `tabbed`, `align` or `tabular` before it to create a tabbing version of a stackengine macro.  The syntax is

`\tabbed`stackengine_macro`[`stackengine_optional_arg.`]`tabbed_stackengine_argument(s)

`\align`stackengine_macrotabbed_stackengine_argument(s)

`\tabular`stackengine_macro`{`column alignments`}`tabbed_stackengine_argument(s)

The `tabbed` versions provides columns, each tabbed to the same alignment; the `align` versions provide `{rlrl...}` alignment; while the `tabular` versions provide user-specified alignments.

I don't support `\hline`s between rows, or even vertical line separators (after all, if you really want a tabular, just use `tabular`), but I do provide specifiable gap widths between adjacent columns, if desired (defaults to 0pt for `tabbed` macros, to 1em [ equal to a "quad"] for `align` commands, and `\tabcolsep` for tabular commands).

The default alignment tabs are the `&` char, but that can be changed.  The default EOL is `\\`, but that can be changed.

The one exception I employ in the naming convention is for `stackengine`'s `\`xxx`Vectorstack` macros, which are named, for the tabbed versions, `\`xxx`Matrixstack`.

**Package is now available at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine**

Below is the MWE employing the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{tabstackengine}
\parskip0.8em\parindent0em
\begin{document}

Setting fixed tab width.
\fixTABwidth{T}
Setting default tabular inter-item gap to 0pt
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}

tabbedShortstack[l]:\\
\framebox{\tabbedShortstack[l]{a & bb & ccc & dddd\\
  1&2&3&$\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}$ \\This&is&a&test}}

tabbedShortstack[c]:\\
\framebox{\tabbedShortstack[c]{a & bb & ccc & dddd\\
  1&2&3&$\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}$ \\This&is&a&test}}

tabularShortstack\{lccr\}:\\
\framebox{\tabularShortstack{lccr}{a & bb & ccc & dddd\\
  1&2&3&$\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}$ \\This&is&a&test}}

Setting default tabbed inter-item gap to 1ex
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}

$\vertMatrixstack[c]{%
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}}
$

$\bracketMatrixstack[c]{%
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & \mathbf{X_{22}} - x_{22} & x_{23}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}}
$

Setting to natural tab width.
\fixTABwidth{F}

$\bracketMatrixstack[c]{%
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & \mathbf{X_{22}} - x_{22} & x_{23}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}}
$

tabbedstackon:\\
\tabbedstackon{a & bb & ccc& dddd}{1&2&3&4}

Setting fixed tab width.
\fixTABwidth{T}

\tabbedstackon{a & bb & ccc& dddd}{1&2&3&4}

Setting default align inter-item gap to 1ex\\
\setstackaligngap{1ex}
alignVectorstack:\\
$
\vert A\vert = \left|\alignVectorstack{
 3.&21 &  4.&3  & 1.& \\
 1.&1  &432.&2  &13.&3\\
56.&83 & 37.&27 &67.&37}
\right|$

\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Steven! I can't wait until your package hits CTAN! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda It has arrived: http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine

Comment: yay, congrats! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a key `columns-width` designed to address that problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}[columns-width=auto,hvlines]
a & b \\
c & Mary had a little lamb
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]