# equations inside matrix/array -- aligning on charater

Tags: amsmath, align, matrices

Suppose I have a system of equations I'd like to present as a vector. Using `amsmath`, something like

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
(2)(2)+(-1)(-3)  \\
(4)(2)+(3)(-3)
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

What I'd like to do is not simply 'center the equations' within the vector (easy enough), but have them center-aligned on the '+' sign. I've tried embedding `align` within `pmatrix`, but that doesn't seem to work. In the end, it isn't critical that the equations are presented within a formal 'matrix' structure -- I'd be satisfied with a 'large enough' left and right delimiter.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `aligned` environment, which is like `align` but to be used inside another math environment

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
(2)(2)&+(-1)(-3)  \\
(4)(2)&+(3)(-3)
\end{aligned}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Alternatively, without using `pmatrix`, you can get large left/right delimiters by using `\left`/`\right` before the delimiters. For example, the following will produce the same result

```
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{aligned}
(2)(2)&+(-1)(-3)  \\
(4)(2)&+(3)(-3)
\end{aligned}
\right)
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

If so, here is the code which uses my beta-version package `\tabstackengine.sty`, found at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\alignVectorstack{
(2)(2) +& (-1)(-3)\\
(4)(2) +& (3)(-3)
}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```