# How to provide more horizontal space between cases in a system?

Tags: spacing, matrices, cases

I have the following ugly system:

[image: Ugly system]

This is my LaTeX code:

```
\newcommand{\Aaa}{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\Ba}{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}

\begin{displaymath}
f: G\longrightarrow GL_2(\R):
\begin{cases}
a\longmapsto \Aaa\\
b\longmapsto \Ba
\end{cases}
\end{displaymath}
```

As you can see, the matrices 'collide'. Is it possible to add some more blanc space between them?

Comment: Love the speech bubble! :D

Comment: Haha, adding some more fun to mathematics. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\\[3ex]` for adding vertical space. But, in this case, you can even do better: if you notice, the matrices are not perfectly aligned to each other. So I propose a slightly different solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Aaa}{%
  \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}%
}
\newcommand{\Ba}{%
  \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

% Simplistic solution with `\\[3ex]`
\begin{displaymath}
\rho_1: V_{24}\longrightarrow GL_2(\C):
\begin{cases}
a\longmapsto \Aaa\\[3ex]
b\longmapsto \Ba
\end{cases}
\end{displaymath}

%% Better solution with horizontal alignment
\begin{displaymath}
\rho_1: V_{24}\longrightarrow GL_2(\C):
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
a&\longmapsto \Aaa\\
b&\longmapsto \Ba
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

In the second solution, not only `aligned` puts the two matrices one over each other, but it also succeeds to leave some vertical space between the rows, without explicit spacing.

[image]

Comment: egreg, maybe you didn't notice but the second matrix is slightly misaligned. :D

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, I noticed; this is why I propose a second solution which doesn't suffer from the problem (and doesn't need explicit spacing).

Comment: Ah wait, they're different? Ah never mind. I thought that was your solution. My bad! :D

Comment: @egreg: Is a combination of an align* environment and \\[12pt] also an option? What's the most consistent solution?

Comment: @Jeroen You can surely space out a bit more in `aligned` if the default spacing is too short. Leave these refinements to the final revision.

Answer (score 5):

You can manually adjust the height between rows if you have super-tall rows using `\\[<len>]`. The following solution also adjusts the location of `b` to make it align with `a`, thereby aligning the matrices (using some `\phantom` and over`lap`ing magic):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\mymatrix}[1]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \rho_1: V_{24}\longrightarrow GL_2(\mathcal{R}):
  \begin{cases}
    a \longmapsto \mymatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1} \\[12pt]
    \hphantom{a}\llap{$b$} \longmapsto \mymatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `tabstackengine` package introduced at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946), you can control the vertical gap between the matrix rows as well as between the "cases", and the horizontal gap between matrix elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\baselineskip}%BASELINE SHIFT BETWEEN MATRIX ELEMENTS
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}% HORIZONTAL GAP BETWEEN MATRIX ELEMENTS
\savestack\Mone{$\bracketMatrixstack[c]{1&0\\0&-\!1}$}
\savestack\Mtwo{$\bracketMatrixstack[c]{0&1\\-\!1&0}$}
\setstackgap{L}{2.8\baselineskip}% BASELINE SHIFT BETWEEN CASE ROWS
\( f: G\longrightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{R}):
\left\{\raisebox{.3\baselineskip}{% .3 IS AN AD HOC CORRECTION
\alignVectorstack{a&\longmapsto \Mone\\b&\longmapsto \Mtwo}}
\right. \)
\end{document}
```

[image]