# Figure out the width of each column

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I want to know the width (e.g., *pt) of each generated column. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  

I want to know the width (e.g., *pt) of each generated column. How can I do it?

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Column1 & Col2 & Column------3 & Column--4 \\ \hline
    I want & to know & the actual & width of each column. \\ \hline
    Is there & any & method & to display the size? \\
    I am & now & using & \{tabular\} \{|l|l|l|l|\} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding. I've updated the question with a code sample.

Comment: You don't really want to display the width, do you? What are you trying to do with the columns' widths?

Comment: @egreg , actually. I have several independent tables. Each of them has four columns and I want to align each column. For example, I want column 1 in table 1 has the same width with column 1 in table 2. If I know the width of columns in a specific table (which is best-fit), I can specify the width of columns of the other tables using p(**pt).

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column?

Comment: This link is different from my problem. I post the actual problem on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141885/how-to-align-the-columns-of-several-tables