# Vertical alignment of degree unit and other elements in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to improve the appearance of the below table such that:

1. The set union symbols `\cup` align vertically with the commas from the 2nd and last rows
2. The middle column angle values are still centered, but vertically aligned to the `\degree` sign

The code that generates the table is:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccr}
\toprule
\rule[-0.6em]{0pt}{1.7em} Elevation range & Azimuth resolution & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$N$} \\ \hline
\rule{0pt}{1.4em} $[-40\degree,40\degree]$             & $5\degree$     & 1224 \\
    $(-60\degree,-40\degree) \cup (40\degree,60\degree)$ & $8\degree$   & 270 \\
    $(-70\degree,-60\degree] \cup [60\degree,70\degree)$ & $10\degree$  & 144 \\
    $(-80\degree,-70\degree] \cup [70\degree,80\degree)$ & $15\degree$  & 96  \\
    $(-90\degree,-80\degree] \cup [80\degree,90\degree)$ & $30\degree$  & 48  \\
\rule[-0.5em]{0pt}{0.5em} $-90\degree,90\degree$         & $360\degree$ & 2   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table looks like:[image]

I would like it to look like:[image]

Comment: none of the answers so far address the fact that the degree signs do not exactly line up (because a square bracket is slightly narrower than the corresponding parenthesis).  i'm unable to undertake a solution for this at the moment (computer problems; i'll try to test it later) but thought the point worth mentioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make `\cup` to align with `,` with the help of boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}   %% provides \widthof

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=3,table-space-text-post=\si{\degree}]r}
\toprule
\rule[-0.6em]{0pt}{1.7em} Elevation range & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Azimuth resolution} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$N$} \\ \hline
\rule{0pt}{1.4em} \makebox[\widthof{$(-60\degree,-40\degree)$}][r]{$[-40\degree$}$,$
\makebox[\widthof{$(40\degree,60\degree)$}][l]{$40\degree]$}             & 5\si{\degree}     & 1224 \\
    $(-60\degree,-40\degree) \cup (40\degree,60\degree)$ & 8\si{\degree}  & 270 \\
    $(-70\degree,-60\degree] \cup [60\degree,70\degree)$ & 10\si{\degree}  & 144 \\
    $(-80\degree,-70\degree] \cup [70\degree,80\degree)$ & 15\si{\degree}  & 96  \\
    $(-90\degree,-80\degree] \cup [80\degree,90\degree)$ & 30\si{\degree}  & 48  \\
\rule[-0.5em]{0pt}{0.5em} \makebox[\widthof{$(-60\degree,-40\degree)$}][r]{$-90\degree$}$,$
\makebox[\widthof{$(40\degree,60\degree)$}][l]{$90\degree$}        & 360\si{\degree} & 2   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With `siunitx` you can have an easier input; I'd prefer `\si{\degree}` to `\degree`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=3,
    table-space-text-post=\si{\degree}
   ]<{\si{\degree}}
  S[table-format=4]
}
\toprule
Elevation range & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Azimuth resolution} & {$N$} \\
\midrule
$[\SI{-40}{\degree},\SI{40}{\degree}]$      &   5 & 1224 \\
$(\SI{-60}{\degree},\SI{-40}{\degree}) \cup 
  (\SI{40}{\degree},\SI{60}{\degree})$      &   8 &  270 \\
$(\SI{-70}{\degree},\SI{-60}{\degree}] \cup
  [\SI{60}{\degree},\SI{70}{\degree})$      &  10 &  144 \\
$(\SI{-80}{\degree},\SI{-70}{\degree}] \cup
  [\SI{70}{\degree},\SI{80}{\degree})$      &  15 &   96 \\
$(\SI{-90}{\degree},\SI{-80}{\degree}] \cup
  [\SI{80}{\degree},\SI{90}{\degree})$      &  30 &   48 \\
$\SI{-90}{\degree},\SI{90}{\degree}$        & 360 &    2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use, say, `\SI{40}{\degree}` instead of `40\si{\degree}`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Just because I was lazy and that edit was simpler. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using the experimental `tabstackengine` package introduced at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946), you can achieve what you requested.

The package extends the `stackengine` package to allow tabbing.

I changed the tab and end-of-align characters for `tabstackengine` from `&` and `\\` to `*` and `/`, so as not to conflict with `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{/}
\setstackTAB{*}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccr}
\toprule
\rule[-0.6em]{0pt}{1.7em} Elevation range & Azimuth resolution & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$N$} \\ \midrule
\alignLongstack{%
  [-40\degree\!\!\!*\,\,,40\degree]/
  (-60\degree,-40\degree) *\cup (40\degree,60\degree)/
  (-70\degree,-60\degree] *\cup [60\degree,70\degree)/
  (-80\degree,-70\degree] *\cup [70\degree,80\degree)/
  (-80\degree,-70\degree] *\cup [70\degree,80\degree)/
  -90\degree\!\!\!*\,\,,90\degree
}
&\Longstack[r]{5^\circ/8^\circ/10^\circ/15^\circ/30^\circ/360^\circ}%
&\Longstack[r]{1224/270/144/96/48/2}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `S` column from [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format = 3]
  S[table-format = 4]
}
\toprule
Elevation range          & \mc{Azimuth resolution} & \mc{$N$} \\
\si{\degree}             & \mc{\si{\degree}}       & \mc{---} \\
\midrule
$[-40 ,40]$              &   5                     & 1224     \\
$(-60,-40) \cup (40,60)$ &   8                     &  270     \\
$(-70,-60] \cup [60,70)$ &  10                     &  144     \\
$(-80,-70] \cup [70,80)$ &  15                     &   96     \\
$(-90,-80] \cup [80,90)$ &  30                     &   48     \\
$ -90, 90$               & 360                     &    2     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that I have defined the unit (°) globally above the numbers in each of the first two columns; this increases the readability, I think.