# How to centralize specific objects in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Lads, when I'm generating this table with letters, it doesn't centralize objects as I would expect, meaning all objects should be as large as the largest one.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{caption}    
\usepackage{siunitx}    

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \captionsetup
  {%
  singlelinecheck = off, 
  justification   = raggedright,
  labelfont       = bf,
  }
  \begin{minipage}[b]{1.0\linewidth}
    \caption{name}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l SS }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{l}{BBBBBBBB}  \\
      \cmidrule{2-3}
     AAAA & {$b$}    & {$c$}     \\ 
      \midrule
       $1$      & Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & b \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Currently I'm getting something like:

[image]

Whereas I'd like to get something like:

[image]

I could probably use tildes (~) as the invisible character, but I believe there's a better way. Isn't there?

Comment: Related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/

Comment: What do you mean by "objects"? Also, please make your code compilable; it seems that there are a few packages you didn't include.

Comment: Sorry about the packages - I've just added them. Well, I meant the size of columns and entries to be centralized.