# Equal spacing in matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to create a matrix that has equal spacing between each of the columns, but so far I have not been very succesful. The code I'm using right now is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
U &= \begin{pmatrix}
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This generates rather ugly output, with the columns containing the exponentials much wider than the others:

[image]

I suppose this is a very stupid and elementary question, but a quick search didn't get me anywhere sadly.

Comment: With equal spacing, do you think the matrix will still fit within the bounds of `\textwidth`? You may consider defining a difference variable `E` (say) to shorten the column width...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done as a TABstack.  The package has a `\fixTABwidth{T}` option.  I've also increased the vertical spacing between lines slightly, to give a more balanced look.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}
\fixTABwidth{T}
U = \parenMatrixstack{
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is actually not a "very stupid and elementary question", as given by the many upvotes at this question: [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/)

Answer (score 7):

Use of `array` to define a newcolumntype `C` with `settowidth` command to determine the widest element in the math array. Same notion is applicable in `pmatrix` case.  As a side note, the `calc` package provides `\widthof{...}` can  be an alternative too.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\usepackage{array}                                              % http://ctan.org/pkg/array

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
\newlength{\mycolwd}                                         % array column width
\settowidth{\mycolwd}{$e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}$}% "width" of $e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t$; largest element in array
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
B=\left [
\begin{array}{*{9}{@{}C{\mycolwd}@{}}}
   e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{array}
\right ]
\end{equation}

\settowidth{\mycolwd}{$e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}$}
\newcommand\w[1]{\makebox[\mycolwd]{$#1$}}

\begin{align}
B &= \begin{pmatrix}
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \w1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pad the columns with something like this (but if you make it this wide, the equation number moves down a line)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\w[1]{\makebox[2.5em]{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
U &= \begin{pmatrix}
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \w0 & \w0 & \w0 & \w0 & \w1 & \w0 & \w0 & \w0 & \w0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
U = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width=auto]
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

With a recent version of the `array` package you can do as follows, using the `w{c}{<length>}` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fwpmatrix}[2][\arraycolsep]
 {%
  \left(
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{$#2$}%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{#1}%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \array{ *{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{w{c}{\dimen@}} }
 }
 {%
  \endarray
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \right)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
U = \begin{fwpmatrix}[-2pt]{e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}}
    e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}
\end{fwpmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{fwpmatrix}{e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t}}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} \\
0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t} & 1 & 1
\end{fwpmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The mandatory argument is the widest entry, the optional argument sets `\arraycolsep`. In the first case, where there are no adjacent columns with the widest entry, it makes sense to use a negative `\arraycolsep`, which is not the case for the second example.

[image]