# Horizontal alignment of matrix in an array by using \llap and \phantom

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, arrays

I want to vertical align two matrices by using a combination of `\phantom` and `\llap`. But neither `\llap` nor `\clap` gives the right spacing.

ps: when I use `\makebox[\widthof{$\infty$}][c]{7}`, it works. I can't explain the difference between them.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
%\def\clap#1{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#1\hss}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
D_0 &= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
    0 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & \infty & \infty & 0 
    \end{array}\right]\\
D_1 &= \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
    0 & \phantom{\infty}\llap{7}  & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & 8 & 2 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't explain the difference between using `\widthof` and combinations of `\phantom` and `\*lap` commands? It's not entirely clear what you mean by the PS reference.

Comment: @Werner I thought, they should have the same result. But in fact only `\widthof` works. I want to know the reason. Thanks

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432061/align-multiple-matrix-equations-and-their-elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best to view the output of certain combinations of `\phantom`s and `\*lap`ping. Below are all possible overlaps (either `\phantom` first, followed by `\*lap`s, or `\*lap`s first, followed by `\phantom`. Column 1 denotes the broad usage, while column 2 shows the actual output. Column 3 shows the `\phantom` text using a light gray colour, just for clarity. A `l`eft `rule` (in red) is inserted *before* the construction; a `c`entre `rule` (green) is inserted *in the middle* of the construction; a `r`ight `rule` (blue) is inserted *after* the construction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\lrule}{\textcolor{red}{\rule[-.3\normalbaselineskip]{.4pt}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}}\hspace*{-.4pt}}
\newcommand{\crule}{\textcolor{green}{\rule[-.3\normalbaselineskip]{.4pt}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}}\hspace*{-.4pt}}
\newcommand{\rrule}{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[-.3\normalbaselineskip]{.4pt}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}}\hspace*{-.4pt}}
\newcommand{\abcd}{\textcolor{black!50}{abcd}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l @{\hspace{4em}} l @{\hspace{4em}} l }
  \verb|\phantom\llap| & \lrule\phantom{abcd}\crule\llap{efgh}\rrule & \lrule \abcd \crule \llap{efgh}\rrule \\
  \verb|\phantom\clap| & \lrule\phantom{abcd}\crule\clap{efgh}\rrule & \lrule \abcd \crule \clap{efgh}\rrule \\
  \verb|\phantom\rlap| & \lrule\phantom{abcd}\crule\rlap{efgh}\rrule & \lrule \abcd \crule \rlap{efgh}\rrule \\
  \verb|\llap\phantom| & \lrule\llap{efgh}\crule\phantom{abcd}\rrule & \lrule \llap{efgh}\crule \abcd \rrule \\
  \verb|\clap\phantom| & \lrule\clap{efgh}\crule\phantom{abcd}\rrule & \lrule \clap{efgh}\crule \abcd \rrule \\
  \verb|\rlap\phantom| & \lrule\rlap{efgh}\crule\phantom{abcd}\rrule & \lrule \rlap{efgh}\crule \abcd \rrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

None of the available options show that `efgh` is set exactly in the middle of `abcd`. So, there's no way to do what you want using the above methods. You'll have to resort to other box manipulations. [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517459/5764) already mentioned [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) (which calculates the maximum width of `<stuff>` automatically for all similar `<tag>`s within `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`; an optional `<align>`ment can be specified, with the default being `c`entre).

You can use `\makebox[\widthof{<other stuff>}]{<stuff>}` which sets `<stuff>` is a box that matches the width of `<other stuff>`. Or, you can measure the widths yourself using boxes or the like (for example, `\newlength{\inftylen} \settowidth{\inftylen}{$\infty$}` and then use `\makebox[\inftylen]{<stuff>}`).

You could also just set the `\infty` in a zero-width box (make a `th`in `\infty`, or `\thinfty` command):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\thinfty}{\makebox[0pt]{$\infty$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  D_0 &= \left[
    \begin{array}{ *{4}{c} }
          0    &     7    &     1    &     6    \\
      \thinfty &     0    &     9    & \thinfty \\
          4    &     4    &     0    &     2    \\
          1    & \thinfty & \thinfty &     0 
    \end{array}
  \right] \\
  D_1 &= \left[
    \begin{array}{ *{4}{c} }
          0    &     7    &     1    &     6    \\
      \thinfty &     0    &     9    & \thinfty \\
          4    &     4    &     0    &     2    \\
          1    &     8    &     2    &     0 
    \end{array}
  \right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer! thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `\fixTABwidth` feature of `tabstackengine` forces all columns to an equal width.  While this will not necessarily match matrices generated from another (`align*` or `array`) technique, by doing them both in `tabstackengine`, perfect alignment can be achieved, in this case, without the mess of `\phantom`s and `\llap`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\begin{document}
\[
D_0 = 
\bracketMatrixstack{
    0 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & \infty & \infty & 0 
}
\]
\[
D_1 = 
\bracketMatrixstack{
    0 & 7  & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & 8 & 2 & 0 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution with `eqparbox`. Two observations, the `bmatrix` environment already defines matrices with extensible brackets, and you don't have to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`:  the latter does it for you, and furthermore, it defines  `\clap` and `\mathclap` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eqparbox, booktabs}
\newcommand*{\eqmathbox}[2][2]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
D_0 &=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4 & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & \eqmathbox{\infty} & \infty & 0
    \end{bmatrix}\\
\addlinespace
D_1 &=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \phantom{\infty}\llap{7} & 1 & 6 \\
    \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
    4 & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
    1 & \eqmathbox{8} & \eqmathbox{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your edit. One never rereads oneself carefully enough! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new column type which reserves the exact space for the infinity symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{i}{>{$}w{c}{\widthof{$\infty$}}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
D_0 &=
\left[\begin{array}{@{}iiii@{}}
  0 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
  \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
  4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
  1 & \infty & \infty & 0 
\end{array}\right]\\
D_1 &= \left[
\begin{array}{@{}iiii@{}}
  0 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
  \infty & 0 & 9 & \infty \\
  4   & 4 & 0 & 2 \\
  1 & 8 & 2 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer your question about how to center something in a space at least as wide as another object?

You can use `\ooalign`, of course:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cenover}[2]{%
  \mathord{% force usage in math mode
    \vphantom{#2}%
    \ooalign{\hphantom{$\m@th#2$}$\cr\hfil$\m@th#1$\hfil\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$2\infty2$

$2\cenover{7}{\infty}2$

\end{document}
```

[image]