# Color a squared Table

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I have a squared Table (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49751/112272). I want to color the cells. How can I do that? I used the colortbl package, but this doesnt work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newlength\celldim
\newlength\fontheight
\newlength\extraheight
\newcounter{sqcolumns}

\newcolumntype{S}{
 @{}
 >{\centering \rule[-0.5\extraheight]{0pt}{\fontheight + \extraheight}%
 \begin{minipage}{\celldim}\centering}
 p{\celldim}
 <{\end{minipage}} 
 @{} }

\newcolumntype{Z}{ @{} >{\centering} p{\celldim} @{} }

\newenvironment{squarecells}[1]
  {\setlength\celldim{4.5em}%
   \settoheight\fontheight{A}%
   \setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}%
   \setcounter{sqcolumns}{#1 - 1}%
   \begin{tabular}{|S|*{\value{sqcolumns}}{Z|}}\hline}
% squarecells tabular goes here
  {\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\nl{\tabularnewline\hline}

\begin{document}
  \Huge
  \begin{squarecells}{4}
    This is a long line & 3  & 2  & 13 \nl
    \cellcolor{red}5  & 10 & 11 & 8  \nl
    9  & 6  & 7  & 12 \nl
    4  & 15 & 14 & 1  \nl
  \end{squarecells}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? I see a bright red cell, with a `5`. Do you mean that the colorfill is somewhat wider than the cell itself?

Comment: if that is the case, you could add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` inside the `\newenvironment{squarecells}`

Comment: Yes the color doen't match the cell. Now I using \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} and it works. Thank you. Can you explain the problem and what tabcolsep changes? (How can I mark the question as answered?)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a somewhat hacky table here. Because you are trying to set the width to `\celldim`, you should consider that by default, every column has some additional spacing between them, which is controlled by the length `\tabcolsep`. So your columns would really be as wide as `\celldim+\tabcolsep`, but your `minipage` would be only `\celldim`-wide.

To add this to your example would mean changing `\tabcolsep` inside you `environment`

```
\newenvironment{squarecells}[1]
  {\setlength\celldim{4.5em}%
   \settoheight\fontheight{A}%
   \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
   \setlength\extraheight{\celldim - \fontheight}%
   \setcounter{sqcolumns}{#1 - 1}%
   \begin{tabular}{|S|*{\value{sqcolumns}}{Z|}}\hline}
% squarecells tabular goes here
  {\end{tabular}}
```

To illustrate what `\tabcolsep` does, here is a quick illustration.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt]
  \centering
  \caption{\texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} unchanged }
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|l}|}
\hline
  Some & random & stuff\\
    foo & bar & baz\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \centering
  \caption{\texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} set to 0 }
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|l}|}
\hline
  Some & random & stuff\\
    foo & bar & baz\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```